# How to deal with non-exhaustive pattern matching?

Tags: haskell

I'm giving my function a list as a parameter but I know that it can ever be either empty list or list with one single element.

When I do pattern matching I get a warning about non-exhaustive patterns.
I can ignore it and the code works but what are some idiomatic ways of doing this?

Comment: A list with 0 or 1 element is precisely what Maybe is.

Comment: How do you know? If you build your list this way, why not build the right thing, a Maybe, in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

There are several techniques. (Some untested code follows.)

#### Restricting the domain

Instead of

```
useList :: [a] -> T
```

we can use a type for non-empty-lists:

```
useList :: NonEmptyList a -> T
```

Willem's answer already explains this.

#### Weakening the codomain

We can instead use

```
useList :: [a] -> Maybe T
useList (x:xs) = Just (...) -- as before
useList []     = Nothing
```

and make the pattern matching to be exhaustive. This is however less convenient for the caller who has to handle the `Nothing` case, which we might know to never happen.

#### Partial, but documented function

We can instead `error` out:

```
useList :: [a] -> T
useList (x:xs) = (...) -- as before
useList []     = error "useList: empty list"
```

This also makes the pattern matching to be exhaustive. It suppresses the warning, at the cost of producing a runtime error message, which we can customize.

In some cases, there is no pragmatic better alternative. For instance, assume we are using an algorithm to solve a complex task, and said algorithm keeps (or at least, should keep) an invariant where the list is always non empty. Then, instead of

```
useList :: [a] -> Int
useList (x:xs) = (...)
useList []     = -1          -- it never happens, so we can return anything
```

it is better to use

```
useList :: [a] -> Int
useList (x:xs) = (...)
useList []     = "useList: internal error -- non null list invariant broken!"
```

The latter makes it possible to detect a bug as early as possible.

#### GADTs proofs

Sometimes we can pass information using GADTs which help to make pattern matching exhaustive. For instance, one could use a type for tagged lists, where the tag represents the emptiness

```
data Tag = Empty | NonEmpty

data List (t :: Tag) a where
   Nil  :: List 'Empty a
   Cons :: a -> List t a -> List 'NonEmpty a
```

Then,

```
useList :: List 'NonEmpty a -> T
useList (Cons x xs) = ...
```

is exhaustive, even if we never handle the `Nil` case.

GHC also allows the "non emptiness proof" to be passed separately:

```
data IsNonEmpty (t :: Tag) where
   IsNE :: IsNonEmpty 'NonEmpty

useList :: IsNonEmpty t -> List t a -> T
useList IsNE (Cons x xs) = ...
```

is also considered to be exhaustive.

Comment: just a few words or some link(s) about what those `'Empty` and `'NonEmpty` and `(t :: Tag)` things are (for someone not in the know to be able to find out more), and this will be perfect. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function where you make it "impossible" to pass such list. Indeed you can implement a function:

```
atLeastTwo :: a -> a -> [a] -> b
```

So here the first two parameters represent the first and the second element, and the third parameter, the list, contains the remaining elements. You thus can implement a function, where the check if a function is exhaustive is useful, since you check that for the last parameter (the elements after the first two elements), all patterns are covered.

or we can work with [**`NonEmpty`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#t:NonEmpty) to represent a non-empty list:

```
atLeastTwo :: a -> NonEmpty a -> b
```

`NonEmpty` is defined as:

```
data NonEmpty = a :| [a]
```

It is thus a type with one data constructor, that forces that the "list" contains at least one element.